# I can' t get email with Facebook Login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I want you to help me about Facebook login and GraphAPI.

I incorporate Facebook login with PHP SDK.
I wrote like below.

```
$fb->get('/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email', $accessToken);
```

But I can't get user's email.

**I tried below:**

1st, I checked if I get AccessToken  : Yes I debugged, and could get first_name, last_name.

2nd, In the first place,  my code is  right or not : Yes. I used GraphAPI explorer and got email.

3rd, I accessed some web pages and used facebook login. In my account, I saw my email and profiles are accessed. But my app doesn't get my email.(but my profile.)

Could you tell me why My app can't get email and How to fix?
Please.

Comment: So when you debug your access token, it shows that you got the `email` permission?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I have just used Facebook accesstoken debugger. 
But in that 'scope' , there is  only 'public_profile'.
Does my comment answer your question?

Comment: So go and ask for that permission, when you make the user log in to your app.

Comment: Thank you, CBroe . As you say,
I missed adding 'permission' to getLoginUrl method...
Sorry....